# Find .closest in 'li' if not in 'div'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the closest method to find an attribute within a div:

```
 .closest($('div[my-attribute]'));
```

The attribute could also exist within an li element:

```
 .closest($('li[my-attribute]'));
```

What is an elegant way of finding the attribute within the 'li' if it is not found in the div?

Something like:

```
var closest = myDiv.closest($('div[my-attribute]'));
if(closest == null){
    closest = myDiv.closest($('li[my-attribute]'));
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), it will help you do exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Isn't it `.closest('div[my-attribute]')` (no surrounding `$()`)?

Comment: @sp00m both works, even tho I would use also just use the string search ( http://api.jquery.com/closest/ )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return the closest of parents containing the attribute "my-attribute", regardless of weather the element is div, li (or anything else).

```
var closest = myDiv.closest('[my-attribute]');
```

Answer (score 1):

`.closest('div[my-attribute], li[my-attribute]');` should work.

Do note that `.closest` traverses up the dom tree, so it will only check ancestors of your base selector.

I.E: if you have a structure like this: `div > ul > (li > a, li > a, li > a)`

then `$("ul").closest("li")` will find nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
var closest = myDiv.closest($('div[my-attribute]')) || myDiv.closest($('li[my-attribute]'));
```

Comment: That's not a ternary operator.

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad haha. I had originally written a ternary operater thinking you could use syntax similar to php, `($something) ?: $default` but then realized that was unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

You can comma separate multiple selectors in jQuery.

http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `*` to select any element.

```
$('*[my-attribute]')
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eZbN7/

Comment: While this might work, if he only wants `li` or `div` elements, this will give him false positives (if other elements can have the attribute)